# SQLITE Error: No Such Table dump restore

Tags: sqlite

I am new to SQL, so sorry if this is a silly question. I have a SQL dump file and I was hoping to restore it. I can open the file with no issues in the MYSQL workbench.

But I get an insane number of errors (most of which are no such table) when I follow the instructions from the SQL website, and run:

> $sqlite3 testDB.db < testDB.sql

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO; you may be better off posting to one of the database sites, or superuser as this is not strictly a programming issue. You should have a look at [mcve]

Comment: your dump missing CREATE TABLE statement,

Answer (score 0):

What are the contents of testDB.sql? You might be getting errors if you are trying to run `INSERT` statements in a table that doesn't exist. Make sure your SQL file has the respective `CREATE TABLE` statements.